# When I install react native app in our folder by using comand "npx react-native init Sarfaraz"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:302
cli.init(root, projectName);
^

TypeError: cli.init is not a function
at run (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:302:7)
at createProject (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
at init (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
at Object. (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: There is some problem in your setup. Please read the documentation first about how to setup react-native project .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cli.init is not a function for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768245/typeerror-cli-init-is-not-a-function-for-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem for new version `0.69.0`

You can use `0.68.2` version.
Just execute the following:

`npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this :
That is error is from the new version 0.69.0 and last version , You can use **npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2**.
when finish setUp  then upgrade to v 0.69.